# Understanding of Proof of Archimedean Property

Tags: real-analysis

*Archimedean Property*. For any $x$, $\varepsilon$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\varepsilon >0$, there is an $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\varepsilon >x$.

Proof. If $x\leq 0$, just take $n=1$. So, assume $x>0$.

Consider $A=${$n\varepsilon: n$ in $\mathbb{N}$}. We can do show that $x$ is less than ar least one element of $A$. Suppose not.

Then, $x$ is an upper bound for $A$. So, by the Dedekind axiom, $A$ has a least upper bound, say $s$. By the definition, $s-1$ is not an upper bound because $s-1<s$. **Then, there is an element in $A$ strictly greater than $s-1$. In other words, there is an $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\varepsilon>s-\varepsilon$. But the implies $(n+1)\varepsilon >s$. This is a contruduction because $(n+1)\varepsilon$ is in $A$ and $s$ is an upper bound of $A$. We are done.**

I couldn't understand boldface sentences.How '' there is an element in $A$ strictly greater than $s-1$''? So, how ''there is an $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\varepsilon>s-\varepsilon$''? Finally, how did we get a contradiction? Can you explain clearly?

Comment: It has to read "$s-ε$  is not an upper bound because ..." The "$s-1$" is a mis-print. -- And think about what it means that "$s$ is the least upper bound".

Comment: @LutzL Yes, thanks.

Comment: @LutzL I think the "s−1" is NOT a mis-print, the definition of the least upper bound says ε could be any positive real, thus permissible to choose  ε=1

Comment: @imath: And what if $ ε=\frac13$? Then $nε>s-1$ does not automatically imply $(n+1)ε>s$.

Comment: @LutzL Yes , it is a bit hard to get that result , but just divide  ε from both sides of nε>x, and you get n>x/ε, then see proof here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Real_Analysis/Properties_of_Real_Numbers#Theorem_.28Archimedes_axiom.29

Comment: Are you trying to prove the Archimedean property by using the Archimedean property? And why do mental gymnastics if the fix is much more simple and straightforward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Claim:** Suppose that $s$ is a least upper bound of $S$. Then for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists some $y\in S$ such that $s-\varepsilon<y\le s$

Suppose there were no such $y$. Then for all $y\in S$, we must have $y\le s-\epsilon$. This means that $s-\varepsilon$ is an upper bound for $S$, and as $\varepsilon>0$ we have $s-\varepsilon<s$. But we declared that $s$ is the *least* upper bound, so this doesn't make sense - $s-\varepsilon$ is smaller than $s$ but is still an upper bound.

So by contradiction there must be such $y$.

**Note:** This property is often known as supremum property, so you should make yourself very familiar with this property - it pops up almost everytime you deal with least upper bounds and usually no detailed explanation is given.

---

Now apply above to your $A$. Then it follows that there is some $y=n\varepsilon$ such that $n\varepsilon>s-\varepsilon$. Clearly this implies that $(n+1)\varepsilon>s$.

However, this is a nonsense. Since $n+1 \in\mathbb{N}$, by definition of $A$, $(n+1)\varepsilon$ is a member of $A$ and is still larger than $s$. But we said $s$ was an upper bound for $S$, so $s$ must be larger than (or equal to) everymember of $A$. So this contradicts the fact that $s$ is an upper bound.

Hence, we can conclude that $A$ is not bounded above (in particular by $x$). So there exist some element $n\varepsilon \in A$ such that $n\varepsilon>x$

Answer (score 0):

$s=\sup A$ is the least upper bound. As $ε>0$, $s-ε<s$ is not an upper bound. There are elements of $A$ that are above $s-ε$. However, all elements of $A$ are of the form $nε$, $n\in\Bbb N$. Thus $nε>s-ε$ for some $n\in \Bbb N$.

Now that implies $(n+1)ε>s$, but $(n+1)$ is also an element of $A$ and thus has to be below all upper bounds, i.e., $(n+1)ε\le s$. As both inequalities can not be true at the same time, one gets a contradiction to the assumption of an upper bound.